# How change orientation of the table in word document using interop?

Tags: c#, ms-word

i am trying to change orientation of the table dynamically when column count increases.

This is the code which i used to create table in my project

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table wordTable;

            wordTable = document.Tables.Add(WordRange, iRowCount, iColCount, ref objMissing, ref objMissing);
```

Guys do you have any idea how to change table orientation when column count increases ?

Answer (score 0):

Tables have no orientation. Tables have width and height, that's all.
What you can do is (and possibly you meant that) changing the page orientation of the page having the table on it.
For this, you need to add a [section break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.sections.add%28v=office.14%29.aspx) (or use [InsertBreak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.insertbreak%28v=office.11%29.aspx) if that fits better for you) and call [TogglePortrait on PageSetup Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.pagesetup_members.aspx) *before* the page you want with different orientation. In case you want to set back original orientation for the rest of the pages, you also need to add -another- section break *after* the page with the table on it.
Hope this helps!